# "Undefined" error when i type "todoList = await TodoList.deployed()" in truffle console

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethereumjs

I was trying this [Beginner tutorial](https://youtu.be/coQ5dg8wM2o) on smart contracts and solidity. I typed truffle compile, truffle migrate and they ran without any error . when i opened truffle console and typed `TodoList = await TodoList.deployed()` as per the tutorial i got error `Undefined`

```
var TodoList = artifacts.require(".\TodoList.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(TodoList);
}
```

Comment: Are  you sure you did every step in the tutorial? Make sure to respect the lowercase/uppercase because they are important in the truffle console.

Answer (score 0):

Try `"./TodoList.sol"` instead of this `".\TodoList.sol"`